# Weird special characters in string while using backtick with single quote or double quote with t function on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, backticks

I have a method named `makeGreeting(someData)` inside the class component in React as

```
makeGreeting(person){
   return `${person.firstName} ${person.lastName} - ${person.greetings}`;
}
```

In the same file inside the render method return section, we have called for ViewGreeting component which is in some other file.`this.props.personData` we are receiving  from another component using user input

```
  <ViewGreeting
     heading={t("common:GREETING_LEVEL")}
     description={t("common:SOME_ANOTHER_LEVEL", {
                  subject: this.makeGreeting(this.props.personData),
                 })}     
   />
```

Our ViewGreeting component in some another file is as follows

```
  <ViewGreeting>
      <h2>{props.heading}</h2>
      <p>{props.description}</p>
   </ViewGreeting>
```

Now when we give data such as:

```
firstName: "fn",
lastName: "ln"
greeting: "Hello"
```

then it prints perfectly in ViewGreeting component as `fn ln - hello`.
but if we give input such as

```
firstName: "fn",
lastName: "ln"
greeting: "Hello'msg"
```

or

```
firstName: "fn",
lastName: "ln"
greeting: "Hello"msg"
```

means single or double quote inside the greeting message then it prints weird characters in ViewGreeting component as:

```
fn ln - hello&#39;msg
```

How should I correct it? I want same greeting in the component as it passed from user input with a single or double quote not these special characters in the Viewgreeting component.

Comment: Looks like that `t` function of yours, or react itself, does some html escaping. (Or is it really a `$` instead of a `&`)? This has nothing to do with the template literal backticks.

Comment: @Bergi yes it is ```&``` not  ```$```.  I have changed it.

Comment: You could sanitize the input in the `onChange` event handler, by replacing `"` with `\"`, for example.

Comment: Does it work if you just pass `description={this.makeGreeting(this.props.personData)}`? If yes, what is the `common:SOME_ANOTHER_LEVEL` translation for your current language?

Comment: @Bergi actually common is used for translating the message to different language like:  "common" : {"SOME_ANOTHER_LEVEL": "greeting for you {{subject}}"}. We can not remove the common section from here.